# Find a pattern in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a string like this:

```
{param1}{param2}{param3}....{myparam paramvalue}{paramn}
```

How can i get the `paramvalue` of `myparam`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specifically get that parameter value, you first have to match the left part:

```
/\{myparam/
```

Followed by at least one space:

```
/\{myparam\s+/
```

Capture characters until a closing curly brace is found:

```
/\{myparam\s+([^}]+)\}/
```

The expression `[^}]+` is a negative character set, indicated by the `^` just after the opening bracket; it means "match all characters except these".

Answer (score 2):

Simple regex:

```
/\({[^ ]+?) ([^}]+?)\}/
```

- `{[^ ]+?)` - it will look for anything at least 1 time occured but space and put it in subpattern
- `([^}]+?)` - it will look for anything at least 1 time occured but `{` and put it in subpattern.

use it with `preg_match()` function

OR

The other simple regex:

```
preg_match('/([a-z0-9]+?) ([a-z0-9]+?)\}/', $str, $matches);
```

- `([a-z0-9]+?)` - a-z 0-9 at least one time not greedy
- `([^}]+?)` -  a-z 0-9 at least one time not greedy

**Output:**

```
Array ( [0] => myparam paramvalue} [1] => myparam [2] => paramvalue )
```

[Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/nih-8yb)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this regex:

```
/\{\w+\s+(\w+)\}/
```

Comment: Works...Thanks..Can you please tell what actually does this exp mean??

Answer (score 1):

```
if(preg_match('/\{'.preg_quote('myparam').' ([^\}]+)\}/', $input, $matches) {
  echo "myparam=".$matches[1];
} else {
  echo "myparam not found";
}
```

1. in preg_match, '{' and '}' are special chars, so they need to be escaped
2. the preg_quote may not be neccessary, as long as "myparam" will never have any special regex chars
3. the (cryptic) part ([^}]+)} matches one or more chars not being a '}', followed by '}'
4. the parantheses make that match available in the third arg to preg_match, $matches in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one as well:

```
.+?\s+([^}]+)
```

**EDIT**

Explanation:

```
.+?     means match everything one or more time but its lazy, will prefer to match as less as it can. 
\s+     means it will match white-spaces one or more time. 
([^}]+) means match everything except `}`(close bracket) one or more time and capture group.
```

Comment: Can you please extend your answer a little bit so that another reader can understand your answer?